# bash read command splits line into words using space as delimiter even though space is not in IFS

Tags: bash

I am using bash.

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
From `help read`
```

This is what the first few lines of `help read` says:

```
$ help read | head
read: read [-ers] [-a array] [-d delim] [-i text] [-n nchars] [-N nchars] [-p prompt] [-t timeout] [-u fd] [name ...]
    Read a line from the standard input and split it into fields.

    Reads a single line from the standard input, or from file descriptor FD
    if the -u option is supplied.  The line is split into fields as with word
    splitting, and the first word is assigned to the first NAME, the second
    word to the second NAME, and so on, with any leftover words assigned to
    the last NAME.  Only the characters found in $IFS are recognized as word
    delimiters.
```

My IFS is just a newline character, i.e. `\n`.

```
$ echo $IFS

$ echo $IFS | od -tcx1                                                                                     
0000000  \n
         0a
0000001
```

Since space is not in IFS, I don't expect read to split the string `"foo bar baz"` into three words. But read does split it into three words.

```
$ read a b c <<< "foo bar baz"; echo $a; echo $b; echo $c
foo
bar
baz
```

Why does it split the string using space as delimiter when the space is not in my IFS?

Comment: You need to test `echo "$IFS" | od -tcx1`.  The blank, tab and newline in `$IFS` would be ignored, and `echo` would be invoked with zero arguments, and just emits a newline, as you demonstrated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is most likely just an issue with how you `echo` `IFS`

```
> IFS=$'\t\n '
> echo $IFS | od -tcx1
0000000  \n
         0a
0000001
> echo -n "$IFS" | od -tcx1
0000000  \t  \n
         09  0a  20
0000003
```

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't look right. Test it like this:

```
bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.45(2)-release (i386-apple-darwin13.1.0)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

IFS=$'\n' read a b c <<< "foo bar baz"; echo "a=[$a]"; echo "b=[$b]"; echo "c=[$c]"
a=[foo bar baz]
b=[]
c=[]

unset IFS
read a b c <<< "foo bar baz"; echo "a=[$a]"; echo "b=[$b]"; echo "c=[$c]"
a=[foo]
b=[bar]
c=[baz]
```